# Mp3 player in WinUi 3 xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, desktop-application, winui-3

I want to play a mp3 audio on a image in WinUi 3 desktop application. Can anyone help me out.
Simple mp3 audio on a image with auto play feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class [Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-22621)

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_audio.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

There are enough examples in the documentation.  I am using this class for a WinUI 3 Internet radio player.

The class doesn't feature an UI, you should build the UI yourself.